# React Native - setState between different JS file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I would like to `setState` from `A` component to `B` component. `A` and `B` are different JS file. I have tried to import `B` to `A` and access the function inside `B`. Also have make the function in `B` to static, then only find out static function no have instance, so I could not access `this` in static.

**A.js**

```
import B from '../B';
class A extends React.Component {
    ChangeBContent(){
        B.SetContent();
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <SpeicalBtn onPress={()=> this.ChangeBContent()}/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = A;
AppRegistry.registerComponent('myApp', () => A);
```

**B.js**

```
class B extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            content:''
        }
    }

    SetContent(){
        this.setState({content:'123'});
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <View>
              <Text>{this.state.content}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = B;
AppRegistry.registerComponent('myApp', () => B);
```

Comment: You are trying to call a `static` method `B.SetContent();` rather, you should find a way to get an instance of `B` and call the method over the instance.

Answer (score 3):

You can do dirty tricks but I think you'll need more cleaner approach.

This is where you'd use state management library such as [redux](http://redux.js.org/) there you have one global store, and you dispatch actions. You can look into this stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36657179/1267177)

Comment: any example i can refer to ? I very new and not familiar in Redux, just read some redux docs, feeling confuse.

Comment: How did you start using react? Getting started from a starter kit is better as you won't have to configure everything yourself at first.

you can go to the link I posted, and work your way up, if you get stuck, comment again, and I'll show you step by step on how to configure.

Comment: I start from react navigation

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap them into another container component.

ContentC.js

```
    class ContentC extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            contentA:'',
            contentB: ''
        }
    }
    SetContentA(){
        this.setState({contentA:'123'});
    }
    SetContentB(){
        this.setState({contentB:'123'});
    }
    render(){
      return(
         <ClassA content={this.state.contentA} />
          <ClassB content={this.state.contentB}/>
        );
      }
    }
```

And now you can use content with `props.contentA` and `props.contentB`